# OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions set in Owin Startup

Tags: c#, oauth, owin

As the title suggests, I need to know if I can set the **OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions** elsewhere.
Basically I need to set the provider up when I have access to **HttpContext** so I can get the current URL.

I have to pass a different **UserManager** instance to **OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.Provider** because my users change based on the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using IAppBuilder.Map to configure different middleware for different URLs into your app.